# How to establish Grafana and Hive connectivity in Cloudera

Tags: hive, cloudera, grafana

I am trying to connect Grafana and create a dashboard from data present in Hive tables.
Not sure if this is possible, hence seeking SO community's help.

If there are any other open source suggestions for dashboard creation from Hive, would also help.